# Check If String Contains Entry From List<String> And Return The Entry

Tags: c#, string, list, contains

Say I have a `List<string> colors`

```
List<string> colors = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "yellow"};
```

And I have a string that I want to search for.

```
string myString = "There is a red apple";
```

I want to check if myString contains anything from the list and return the search.

In this case, the program should find `"red"` and output `"red"` in the console.

I was able to check up to the contain part with `Any()`, but how can I return the result?

```
colors.Any(myString.Contains); //this only returns a bool I believe
```

Above method I use is half way there, how can I get the actual result?

--EDIT--

It's safe to assume that `myString` will at most contains only 1 from `colors`, and the match will always be whole-word match.

Comment: Do you want case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: @ErikPhilips case insensitive

Comment: If `colors` contains "app" should that match, given that your string has the sub-string "app" within "apple"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `Split` your string on white space and then use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
var matching = colors.Intersect(myString.Split());
```

The above would return one item in `matching`, i.e. `red`

If you want **case-insensitive** then you can do:

```
var matching = colors.Intersect(myString.Split(), 
                                StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

EDIT: If you are looking for Partial matching or multiple words matching then you can do:

```
List<string> colors = new List<string> { "red", "red apple", "yellow", "app" };
string myString = "There is a red apple";

var partialAllMatched =
    colors
       .Where(r => myString.IndexOf(r, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0);
```

This would return  you:

```
red
red apple
app
```

Comment: This only matches whole words in `myString`, not multiple word sub-strings or partial word sub-strings.  It's unclear whether or not that's the intended behavior.

Comment: @Servy, from the example in the question, I don't think OP is looking to get partial word matching or multiple words matching.

Comment: From the example in the question, namely `colors.Any(myString.Contains);`, the opposite seems more likely.  Regardless, he'd need to clarify for either of use to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use :

```
var result = colors.FindAll(myString.Contains);
```

This returns a array with the output inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try regex search on this one.

Build a search pattern with or operator and each color. Something like this "(red|blue|yellow)". Not sure if the pattern matches regex syntax but you get the idea.

Then in next step let regex use your pattern and try match it to provided text. In your case the text is myString.

Here is an example:

```
class TestRegularExpressions
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] sentences = 
        {
            "C# code",
            "Chapter 2: Writing Code",
            "Unicode",
            "no match here"
        };

        string sPattern = "code";

        foreach (string s in sentences)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0,24}", s);

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", sPattern);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
/* Output:
           C# code  (match for 'code' found)
           Chapter 2: Writing Code  (match for 'code' found)
           Unicode  (match for 'code' found)
           no match here
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see the use of [LINQ Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so here it is:

```
var colors = new[] {"red", "blue", "white", "black"};
const string str = "There is a red apple with black rocket.";

var foundWords = colors.Where(str.Contains).ToList();
```